# Smooth movement with touches

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

What method should I use to smoothly move my sprite that responds to a touch?
I am using the CCMoveTo method with the duration and the position of my touch is. My sprite moves but it (the sprite) skips over to the position which makes it jumpy. I want the sprite(one sprite controllable by the user) to follow my finger as it drags across the screen. Thank you in advance :)

-Dustin

*EDIT

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
    return YES;
}
- (void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
    CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace: touch];
    //[player stopAllActions]; 
    //[player runAction: [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:.1 position:location]];
    player.position = location;
}
```

That's the code after I set the sprite directly to the location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Like this...

```
- (void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
    sprite.position = location;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In touchMoved, set the sprite's position directly instead of getting CCMoveTo to do it.

Comment: It still just skips, I want the sprite to follow my finger. Check my original post for my code.